# How should I understand "ought" in this verse?

Tags: meaning, phrases, songs

I was wondering how should I interpret this verse from the old union song **Solidarity Forever**:

> **What's the ought with have in common with** those greedy parasites?

---

I'm split between

> **What responsibility do we have towards** those greedy parasites?

and

> **What responsibilities do we share with** those greedy parasites?

The first reading is more consistent with the theme of the song but without contex the second seems more correct (a common ought -> a shared responsibility), which makes me think it might be an idiom or an old usage I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you hear it or read it somewhere? The correct start of the second verse:

> Is there **aught** we hold in common with the greedy parasite,
>   Who would lash us into serfdom and would crush us with his might?

"Aught" is an archaic word meaning "anything at all".

[Aught](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aught)

[Solidarity Forever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solidarity_Forever)

Comment: I think "aught" is still used frequently in some areas, although it is often spelt (and pronounced) "owt", which pairs with its opposite -  "nowt".

Comment: "You don't get owt for nowt" is Yorkshire dialect.